# InstaBot how to send multiple messages to same user Python?

Tags: python

So ive tried this:

```
with open("rawtext.txt", encoding="utf8") as f:
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    bot.send_messages(line, ["REDACTED_USER"])
```

But the bot only sends the first line as a message (I'm using the instabot library).
This is what is shown in the console log while running:

> 2022-09-23 16:54:00,259 - INFO - Going to send 1 messages.
> 100%|██████████| 1/1 [00:01<00:00,  1.52s/it]
> 2022-09-23 16:54:03,789 - INFO - Going to send 1 messages.
> 0%|          | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]

Comment: How is the posted code related to your (very terse) question?

Comment: I would try to put in a time.sleep(2), because probably you are putting a strain on the instagram message API. If that does not work, try to send messages to multiple people.

Comment: Ok, so basically I want to use this bot to send whole songs verse by verse as messages on instagram and i've put the bot.send_messages command in a loop that is supposed to go through every verse and send them individually. My problem is that after sending the first messages it doesn't loop again and it just sits there doing nothing. No exit code no anything. I'm sorry if I'm explaining this like an absolute retard but english is not my first language. Thank you for editing the code part btw.

Comment: You know how to edit the question. Why do you put info and explanation into comments?

Answer (score 0):

There is a default delay in the bot if you send messages to users. This is to prevent a ban from Instagram. I think the creator of the bot has done this on purpose, so I would advise not to change this. To summarize:

- The delay between messages is 5-10 minutes.
- The maximum amount of messages per day is 50-100 minutes.

Below you'll find code references to support these findings.

1. The random delay ([source](https://github.com/ohld/igbot/blob/d68b55015322898c3842c92dcc5989581043252e/instabot/bot/bot.py#L177)):

   ```
   message_delay=random.randint(300, 600)
   ```
2. Maximum messages per day ([source](https://github.com/ohld/igbot/blob/d68b55015322898c3842c92dcc5989581043252e/instabot/bot/bot.py#L155)):

   ```
   max_messages_per_day=random.randint(50, 100),
   ```
3. The delay calculation ([source](https://github.com/ohld/igbot/blob/d68b55015322898c3842c92dcc5989581043252e/instabot/bot/bot.py#L484)):

   ```
   def delay(self, key):
       """
       Sleep only if elapsed time since
       `self.last[key]` < `self.delay[key]`.
       """
       last_action, target_delay = self.last[key], self.delays[key]
       elapsed_time = time.time() - last_action
       if elapsed_time < target_delay:
           t_remaining = target_delay - elapsed_time
           time.sleep(t_remaining * random.uniform(0.25, 1.25))
       self.last[key] = time.time()
   ```

3. The delay usage ([source](https://github.com/ohld/igbot/blob/d68b55015322898c3842c92dcc5989581043252e/instabot/bot/bot_direct.py#L7))

   ```
   def send_message(self, text, user_ids, thread_id=None):
       """
       :param self: bot
       :param text: text of message
       :param user_ids: list of user_ids for creating group or
       one user_id for send to one person
       :param thread_id: thread_id
       """
       user_ids = _get_user_ids(self, user_ids)
       if not isinstance(text, str) and isinstance(user_ids, (list, str)):
           self.logger.error("Text must be an string, user_ids must be an list or string")
           return False

       if self.reached_limit("messages"):
           self.logger.info("Out of messages for today.")
           return False

       self.delay("message")
       urls = self.extract_urls(text)
       item_type = "link" if urls else "text"
       if self.api.send_direct_item(
           item_type, user_ids, text=text, thread=thread_id, urls=urls
       ):
           self.total["messages"] += 1
           return True

       self.logger.info("Message to {user_ids} wasn't sent".format(user_ids=user_ids))
       return False
   ```

Comment: Ok, found it. Should I set it to a smaller fixed value?

Comment: I am not sure, because you might get a ban. In this [example](https://github.com/ohld/igbot/blob/master/examples/message_users.py#L38) they even set a delay in the client code.

Comment: I've played with some values there but now it hits me with this after sending the first message: "2022-09-23 17:19:25,074 - ERROR - Error unknown send request"

Comment: Better stick with the defaults :)